# Missing wso2is stub maven dependencies

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I'm trying to migrate my project from wso2is-5.2.0 to wso2is-5.3.0.

My project has dependencies to many wso2is stub.

For exemple for oauth2 webservices I have

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.wso2.carbon.identity</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth.stub</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.3</version>
</dependency>
```

witch is available in wso2is nexus repository :

http://maven.wso2.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases/org/wso2/carbon/identity/org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth.stub/5.1.3/

in wso2is-5.3 according to $wso2is_home/repository/components/plugins the stub is now in version  5.3.4
witch in not available in
http://maven.wso2.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases/org/wso2/carbon/identity/org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth.stub/

Same problem for artifacts

- org.wso2.carbon.identity.user.registration.stub
- org.wso2.carbon.identity.mgt.stub
- org.wso2.carbon.user.mgt.stub
- org.wso2.carbon.authenticator.stub
- org.wso2.carbon.um.ws.api.stub

I cannot keep previous version because wso2is-52 client stub calling wso2is-53 webservice I got error like this for exemple :

`Caused by: java.lang.Exception: org.apache.axis2.databinding.ADBException: Unexpected subelement {http://dto.oauth.identity.carbon.wso2.org/xsd}state`

Are the correct version going to be deployed later or a new nexus repository exists somewhere else or did I missed something ?

Regards

Comment: can you share the pom.xml or a project shell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The group ids of the identity components were changed due to some technical requirement. So you have to refer the dependencies with the new group ids.

The `org.wso2.carbon.authenticator.stub` group id should remain unchanged as `org.wso2.carbon` because it comes from carbon kernel. The group ids of the rest of the listed ones should be changed as follows.

- `org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth.stub` should have `org.wso2.carbon.identity.inbound.auth.oauth2`
- `org.wso2.carbon.identity.user.registration.stub`, `org.wso2.carbon.identity.mgt.stub`, `org.wso2.carbon.user.mgt.stub` all should have `org.wso2.carbon.identity.framework`
- `org.wso2.carbon.um.ws.api.stub` should have `org.wso2.carbon.identity.user.ws`

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I found out that the groupId/artifactId/version is defined in the stub jar in a METAF-INF/maven/pom.properties, I didn't see that the groupId changed